# Does Ubuntu support unlocking full-disk encrypted internal drive(s) automatically with TPM?

Tags: boot, encryption, thinkpad, tpm

Does Ubuntu (and official flavors) support disk encryption that'll automatically unlock using the device's TPM module?  Would it be possible to do that during install?  What's the best, pain-free, tool to use if I wanna do it post-install (preferably GUI-based)?

With Windows, we got Bitlocker, and that has the option to use TPM to automatically unlock the drive at boot, unless there's a change in BIOS/UEFI.

I have a [4th gen Lenovo X1 Yoga](https://www.lenovo.com/ca/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x1/X1-Yoga-Gen-4/p/22TP2TXX14Y), running on Kubuntu.  Planning on reinstalling it with Btrfs or ZFS as the primary file system.