# How to automatically unlock on boot a Ubuntu encrypted boot disk drive?

Tags: boot, encryption, automount, autostart

Please, there is any way to easily auto unlock encrypted boot disk on Ubuntu, as we have using bitlocker on Windows? I saw [this process](https://newbedev.com/using-a-single-passphrase-to-unlock-multiple-encrypted-disks-at-boot), but I don't think that it will work (seems that I am not using LUKS) and I was looking for an easiest way for a non-expert in Linux env.

Setup: Ubuntu desktop on encrypted disk over LVM (configured on Ubuntu OS install process), mobo have TPM 2.0 onboard

lsblk -f:

```
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                           
sr0                                                                           
nvme0n1
│                                                                             
├─nvme0n1p1
│    vfat   FAT32       2BD7-7851                               504,9M     1% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2
│    ext4   1.0         d42fb156-cc61-49a2-8ffa-64aa7604c7f5      1,2G    18% /boot
└─nvme0n1p3
     crypto 2           5c07fc32-587d-4ab0-a6b1-a0199299fd27                  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt
     LVM2_m LVM2        DmsXsc-OaTX-74hb-CGRz-6i8c-L3EM-inTJ98                
    ├─vgubuntu-root
    │  ext4   1.0         9fa27263-183e-4bba-8b07-e2633de6ac5b    843,7G     2% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
    │                                                                           /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1
       swap   1           4c4627d6-d802-46f9-964c-8933c7dfbd7a                  [SWAP]
Select allOpen in new window
```

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394124/does-ubuntu-support-unlocking-full-disk-encrypted-internal-drives-automaticall) but also without answer

Thanks

Comment: Easily? Very. https://ubuntu.com/blog/tpm-backed-full-disk-encryption-is-coming-to-ubuntu Just use "hardware-backed full disk encryption" in the installer (you need to wipe the disk)

Comment: Thank you @DanielT!! I noticed that it's only available on 23.10 and I was trying to use on 22.04. I wiped it and used on 23.10 without issue an you described :)
I also noticed that it requires a very specific set of hardware, it requires TPM2 and also TCG2, some older motherboards with TPM2 integrated still uses TCG1.2, I got some problems using an older mobo until figure out lol